# Migrating SBS 2008 to new hardware

Tags: migration, windows-sbs-2008

We have an SBS 2008 installation and are testing a disaster recovery solution by re-installing in Migration Mode.

Step 5 in the migration document from Microsoft discusses;

> Demote and remove the Source Server from the network

We'd like to fully test this and get the backup box up and running before signing it off as a working solution.

Our concern is that, even if we isolate the test machine on a difference subnet from our production LAN, there is some kind of licensing consequence for our running box - via some kind of de-activation signal sent over the net, perhaps - should we continue through the final steps.

Can anyone confirm or deny whether any kind of de-activation occurs? Perhaps paranoia, but thought best to check since we really can't have our live systems shut down.

Comment: IMO, using SBS migration as your DR isn't rally a good way to implement DR. Why not use Windows Server backup or some third party product that can perform bare metal restores to dissimilar hardware?

Comment: This is using Windows Server Backup..

Comment: If you're using Windows Server backup to backup the source machine then why are you performing a migration? Why are you not just restoring the backup to new hardware? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivation does occur, but I believe [it takes 21 days](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469604%28WS.10%29.aspx).  The safest route would be to discuss this with Microsoft and/or your reseller.

(I'm afraid your question will likely be closed because it's basically a licensing question.)

Comment: +1 - You get a 21 day grace period before the machine starts having problems. I haven't seen how SBS 2008 "complains"-- SBS 2003 bluescreens with a SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION. I suspect 2008 does something similiar.